# Different outcome of substr() when using variable vs getting input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring, substr

I have some javascript that I'm using in a few places to check the last 3 characters of an email address. What I don't understand is why I get different outcomes when I'm getting the substring of a set variable vs when I grab the input value.

The code below will alert with value: "com"

```
var email = "blah@test.com";
alert(email.toLowerCase().substr(email.length - 3, 3));
```

However, this code that grabs the input value alerts with a value: "om"

```
alert($("#email").val().toLowerCase().substr($("#email").length - 3, 3));
```

Can anyone explain to me why the above two lines of code have different outcomes?

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bjopg2gz/2/)

Comment: `$("#email").length` is not the same as `$("#email").val().length`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to pass the `length` of the `value` of the text box, not the `length` of `selected elements`,

```
alert($("#email").val().toLowerCase().substr($("#email").val().length - 3, 3));
//-------------------------------------------------------^^^^^
```

And the best approach for accomplishing this would be,

```
var value = $("#email").val().toLowerCase();
alert(value.substr(-3));
```

Passing start value in negative will strip the string from the behind.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bjopg2gz/3/)

Comment: But of course, store `$("#email").val()` in a variable instead of repeating.

Comment: wow, so simple. Thanks! @Oriol Yes, I plan to store it in a variable so that it's not repeated.

Comment: @Jmh2013 Glad to help! :)